# How can I tell which release my org is running?

Tags: release

Usually you can tell what release (e.g. Winter '14) you are running under by looking at the logo in the top left, but if that has been customized or removed it's not an option. Is there some place in the setup or settings that let's you know what release you are running?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

On the Home tab, on the top right of the screen is a link to Discover Winter '14. This indicates your release.

[image]

Comment: Well! I didn't find this in Lightning interface. Is there any similar way to check it in Lightning..

Answer (score 25):

**Or if you like to see it in xml, goto /services/data/ on your instance.**

[https://[instance].salesforce.com/services/data/](https://na14.salesforce.com/services/data/)

works with a lightning url too.
https://[domain].lightning.force.com/services/data

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can see in more detail what release and patch level your instance is on in the Releases section of the known issues page.

For example this page, which lists fixes for Summer 14, https://success.salesforce.com/issues_releases_view?release=190000000, also shows the patch level of each instance - at the time of writing "Spring '14 Patch 20.2". This can be useful if you see discrepancies in behaviour between orgs on different instances.

Answer (score 7):

You could go to setup Build | Develop | Apex Classes and click "new".

This will let you see what the options for API version are, API 29 = Winter 14.

I'm sure there's a nicer way to do it though!

Comment: Drawback is that this is not available in enterprise production environments

Comment: You can create Visualforce Page

Answer (score 7):

The **/speedtest.jsp** page that is available in each instance includes a **Release** section that includes the current patch release. This can be useful if you don't immediately know which pod your instance is currently running on.

[image]

---

In 2016 Trust was updated to include a REST API - See [What's New in Trust](https://trust.salesforce.com/en/whats-new-trust/).

Of particular interest is the [new REST API](https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/docs/).

With that we can do a single unauthenticated GET call and parse the exact `releaseVersion` from the JSON response.

E.g.

```
https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/instances/na5/status
```

Extract from the JSON response showing **Winter '17 Patch 13.5**

```
{
  "key": "NA5",
  "location": "NA",
  "environment": "production",
  "releaseVersion": "Winter '17 Patch 13.5",
  "status": "OK",
  //...
}
```

You can also use https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/instances/status/preview to see the releaseVersion of all the public pods.

Comment: The speedtest page would be ideal except that it apparently doesn't report the release for partial sandboxes.

Answer (score 4):

In lightning experience, the option to view the current release (from the UI) is at the top right corner of the screen, help and training (question mark icon):
[image]

However, as of recent releases, this is no longer included, and you have to sleect the release notes in order to easily view what version you are supposed to be on.
[image]

Loading screens will also give you a hint as to what version you are on:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't show what patch version my sandbox is running.

Comment: Salesofrce changed/removed it from the menu options. Other than the loading screen, you will have to refer to other answers,

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**
1.Login Your Org --> SetUp --> Company Information -->Instance --> Take the value of this
2.Open the link --> trust.salesforce.com --> status.salesforce.com --> status button click --> search with above instance --> After it finds the instance result --> click on the link --> Right side it show the Instance Details.

**Option 2 :**Simple, Refresh the screen it shows the logo and image of release version, Sometimes it will be very fast cant see the details.