# Developer console Code Coverage

Tags: developer-console, code-coverage

I am not able to view the classes/triggers which are not covered by test classes.It only shows the classes/triggers which are covered atleast one percent.I need to tackle test coverage  of those classes/triggers which are not covered at all.How to find those classes/triggers.Is there any other way ?

Comment: This may be a release issue; a sandbox on Spring '14 shows me classes with 0%, but an org on Winter '14 does not.

Comment: @MikeChale Is there a way that I can find out whether my sandbox got upgraded to Spring 14 or not ?

Comment: Yes: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18905/how-can-i-tell-which-release-my-org-is-running

Comment: @MikeChale my sandbox is on Winter 14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @Mike Chale.It looks like known issue of Winter 14.Please find the [link](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T1m1AAC)