# Install Managed Package Into Sandbox Fails on All Lightning Component Bundles

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, sandbox, install

I have developed an app for the Salesforce platform and have successfully created a beta managed package ready for testing on one of our sandboxes. however when I try to install the package on the sandbox, it fails with a large number of errors detailing that every part of a lightning bundle does not exist. This same error happened when attempting to install a dependency app from the App Exchange directly into the sandbox, but I got around this by installing it into the Test Enterprise Org.

does anyone know why this happens when trying to install to a sandbox? How can I get around this problem with a beta managed package?

This is a portion of the 58 errors that I receive:

```
1.  No EVENT named markup://it4sxr:SourceAddedEvent found
SourceAddedEvent: No EVENT named markup://it4sxr:SourceAddedEvent found

2.  No CONTROLLER named js://it4sxr.SourceList found
SourceListController: No CONTROLLER named js://it4sxr.SourceList found

3.  No HELPER named js://it4sxr.SourceList found
SourceListHelper: No HELPER named js://it4sxr.SourceList found

4.  No STYLE named css://it4sxr.SourceList found
SourceList: No STYLE named css://it4sxr.SourceList found

5.  No COMPONENT named markup://it4sxr:SourceList found
SourceList: No COMPONENT named markup://it4sxr:SourceList found

6.  No CONTROLLER named js://it4sxr.ImportJobService found
ImportJobServiceController: No CONTROLLER named js://it4sxr.ImportJobService found

7.  No HELPER named js://it4sxr.ImportJobService found
JobServiceHelper: No HELPER named js://it4sxr.ImportJobService found

8.  No COMPONENT named markup://it4sxr:ImportJobService found
ImportJobService: No COMPONENT named markup://it4sxr:ImportJobService found
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe this a bug - I hit the same issue yesterday, and have raised a case with support - I'll update here if I get any updates. But I would try installing it in a regular dev org if you can - seems to be a Sandbox issue

Comment: ah that is a shame -  I shall spin up another dev org for testing purposes, thanks :)

Comment: Looks very similar to this KI from last summer's release...
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008jMrQAI&title=package-install-fails-with-error-no-controller-named-js-xxxxxx-found-or-we-couldn-t-retrieve-the-design-time-component-information-for-component

Comment: It does, I came across this earlier in my search for answers before asking the question on here. Your dev org solution does the job.

Comment: It's happening to us too. I hope they fix this soon.

Comment: I can confirm that we began seeing this too as of yesterday, EXACT same symptom. All sandbox instances fail, all production/dev/test instances work fine. I found at least 3 past known issues on the Salesforce known issues page from past releases that were all marked as resolved, but it's obviously happened again. If Salesforce posts a "Known Issue" for this one, please post it here so we can upvote it.

Comment: One thing to [check would be the release version that the orgs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/34950/102) that work are on vs the version of the sandboxes that are failing. Sounds like the problem is to sandboxes, but it might reveal something. E.g. It might be specific to Summer '18 Patch 19.0 that is showing up on most sandboxes.  Most other orgs are on Summer '18 Patch 18.7

Comment: I have just checked the release version for the orgs as @DanielBallinger has suggested. The sandbox is running patch 19 and the dev orgs + enterprise org used for testing and demos are running patch 18.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it seems to be an internal Salesforce bug there isn't much you can do about it until they resolve it.

They are onto it:

> Team is looking into it right now. W-5394323 for reference if you have a support case or talk to a support agent.
>    - [Farhan Tahir](https://twitter.com/tahir_farhan/status/1034888692240994305)

---

[Circumstantial evidence suggests Summer'17 Patch 19.0](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/230345/install-managed-package-into-sandbox-fails-on-all-lightning-component-bundles/230604#comment350963_230345) could be responsible. So if you can avoid deploying to orgs with that patch version you can avoid the problem. YMMV.

Comment: Unfortunately all CS* instances are currently showing as Patch 19.0 :(

Comment: And all scratch orgs use CS Instances as far as I know? So right now, I can't install packages into my scratch orgs to do any testing...

Comment: I was just able to install a package that previously failed into a new scratch org, so looks like the updates being pushed out might be resolving this issue?

Comment: As per [How can I tell what is changing in Salesforce as they patch each pod?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/98826/102) - I couldn't find any public known issues for 214019100. Only [214019000](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_releases_view?release=214019000)