# Workaround for "Install Managed Package Into Sandbox Fails on All Lightning Component Bundles"?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, sandbox, isv, package-install

We're experiencing [this issue - "Install Managed Package Into Sandbox Fails on All Lightning Component Bundles"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/230345/install-managed-package-into-sandbox-fails-on-all-lightning-component-bundles) that is affecting other vendors as well, where our package with new Lightning components cannot be installed into sandbox environments. Prod environments work fine.

This error has happened with a few older Salesforce releases, and got fixed, but it's likely to be a matter of days or more before that happens.

In the meantime, anyone got a workaround that allows us to deploy new Lightning components to customer sandboxes? We have one customer who desperately needs our new components and can't accept them right now.

Comment: Presumably, if it's happening at this level, there's no workaround short of "install in prod and refresh sandbox."